# Prestashop confirmation email

Tags: email, prestashop, confirmation

I am trying to configure my prestashop store, but ran up against a problem.

When a costumer buys a product, they should receive an order confirmation email.

If the site is being browsed in english, they do receive this message exactly as they should. When they however access the site in danish (my sites main language), they do not receive any mail.

I am not really sure where the problem might be, so don't really know what aditional info to post here, but if any additional info is needed to solve this problem please say so! [:)]

I use the default bootstrap theme, and prestashop 1.6.0.9
Payment module ePay.

Orders placed in english get a status right away, while orders placed in danish do not.
I tried a clean install of prestashop, but the problem was already there.
Any suggestions where i would have to look to solve this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In prestashop root directory you should have a mails folder. Check that folder. Inside the mail directory should be language folders. For example we only offer english so inside that folder there is only an en folder which contains all of prestashop's mail templates for english. Our folder structure looks something like this.

```
prestashop
|
|--mails
   |
   |--en
```

You should have two folders in yours. One for English and one for Danish

```
prestashop
|
|--mails
   |
   |--en
   |--da
```

Comment: Hey, those folders are both there. We have checked if all files were there, and we could not see any lacking files